# In PDF, why are these two interval notations the same?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

0 <= x <= 10

0 < x < 10

When finding the probabilty for each of those ranges, why are they attributed to be the same answer? In other words, why does adding the equals symbol make it have the same probability as P(0 < X < 10)?

Comment: If you have a continuous distribution think about what $P(10)$ is.

Comment: The set of two points has measure zero.

Answer (score 4):

The difference between $P[0\leqslant X\leqslant 10]$ and $P[0\lt X\lt 10]$ is $P[X=0]+P[X=10]$. Now, if $X$ has a density, then $P[X=x]=$ $____$ for every $x$, hence $P[X=0]+P[X=10]=$ $____$.

Answer (score 0):

Integrate $\int_{10}^{10}f(x)dx$ and $\int_{0}^{0}f(x)dx$. What do you get?